# Getting AWK error while transpose some message content

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, bash-scripting, awk

I trying to transpose below text into single line with pipe separated, i getting some error if text is start with number% , what is the issue, any other command is there

**Sample content in txt file**

```
PROMOTIONAL - ATL
36% Extra Money : NML 60=65(Rs.47.85 now, rest Rs.17.15 in 48hrs) + A&B @20p/m +  ACCC DD  for 11 day. 100=100 1 days.
2017-11-21
09:00 AM
10:00 PM
ENGLISH
OR
0.0
10
```

awk command using :

```
awk '{printf NR==1?$0:"|"$0}' text
```

Error:

```
PROMOTIONAL - ATLawk: (FILENAME=text FNR=2) fatal: not enough arguments to satisfy format string</br>
    `|36% Extra Money : NML 60=65(Rs.47.85 now, rest Rs.17.15 in 48hrs) + A&B @20p/m +  ACCC DD  for 11 day. 100=100 1 days.'
         ^ ran out for this one
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the first argument to `printf` should be a format string. In format strings, percent signs are treated specially.  To avoid the problem with your input containing a `%` sign, try:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s",(NR==1?"":"|")$0}' text
PROMOTIONAL - ATL|36% Extra Money : NML 60=65(Rs.47.85 now, rest Rs.17.15 in 48hrs) + A&B @20p/m +  ACCC DD  for 11 day. 100=100 1 days.|2017-11-21|09:00 AM|10:00 PM|ENGLISH|OR|0.0|10
```

Here, the first argument to printf, being the format string, is `%s`.  The `%s` instructs awk to take the second argument and format it as a string.  The second argument can include `%` or not, it doesn't matter.

Or, equivalently, we can use:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s",(NR==1?"":"|"),$0}' text
PROMOTIONAL - ATL|36% Extra Money : NML 60=65(Rs.47.85 now, rest Rs.17.15 in 48hrs) + A&B @20p/m +  ACCC DD  for 11 day. 100=100 1 days.|2017-11-21|09:00 AM|10:00 PM|ENGLISH|OR|0.0|10
```